# Import variable from css to scss

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

The idea is simple, declare a variable in .css and use it on .scss file.

index.css

```
:root {
  --primary: rgb(65, 120, 95);
}
```

variable.scss

```
@import './index';

$color: var(--primary);


.my-color: {
  color: $color
}
```

is not working.
I do know that if you do

```
$primary: rgb(65, 120, 95);

.my-color: {
  color: $color
}
```

is working.

But I want to set the variables in css file.
Thank you

Comment: you cannot .... CSS variables doesn't exist outside the CSS world

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use CSS variables this way. You can import a CSS file for reference in your SCSS file but cannot access the CSS variables directly. You can only share variables between SCSS files.

What you are better off doing is making `index.css` into another SCSS file, and then declare your variables in `variable.scss`. Then import `variable.scss` into `index.scss` which will now have access to all variables. You would just need to change the files being referenced so that they are pointing to `index.scss`.

See below.

**variables.scss**

```
$primary: rgb(65, 120, 95);
```

**index.scss**

```
@import "/variables";

.my-color: {
  color: $primary
}
```